# PageObject model for a dynamic id? c#

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, pageobjects

Wondering if it is possible to page object an id that will be dynamic?

Example code below:

```
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {

        if (randNumber == row.FindElement(By.Id($"r-number-{index}")).Text)
        {
            row.FindElement(By.Id($"view-record-{index}")).Click();
            return;
        }
        index++;
    }
```

`By.Id($"r-number-{index}")).Text` is used in multiple places and in multiple specflow steps so would be great to be able to turn it into a page object.

`RandPage.RandNumber+index+` in simple terms what I would ideally need.

Anyone knows of any possible ways?

Comment: You could return a collection of items that match that description. However you probably need to know the index when you are searching for it or handle a collection of records that get returned. Or are you wanting some random row within the collection?

Comment: We pass in the identifier for the row we need in our specflow step, so we know what row we are looking for, but we need to check all the other rows that they dont contain what were looking for. The value we pass in can be any value at any point (depending on the test) so its not always going to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
private IList<IWebElement> ListOfElements => Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//p[contains(@id,'r-number-')]"));
//this finds all the p elements on the page with an id that contains r-number-

    public void ClickEachOne()
    {
        // click each element in that list

        foreach (var element in ListOfElements)
        {
            element.Click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aye thats what we ended up going with after quite a lot of headaches! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add parameter in the PageObject constructor which will be the index.

And then you can create the page for that index and use it.

E.g:

```
public class MyPage
    {
            private int _index = 0;
            ...

            public MyPage(int index)
            {
               _index = index;
            }
            ...
            public MyMethod()
            {
                //do something with the _index here
            }
    }
```